# HTML Cross-Origin Request Blocked when read file from site

Tags: html, css, fonts

I read a `.css` file from my site url into my site;

**like this:**

```html
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sample.com/styles.css"
...
```

And in that file, I defined a font;

**like this:**

```css
...
@font-face{
   font-family:'SomeFont';
   src: url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
...
```

( That is, the font is located at address `https://sample.com/myfont.ttf` )

But, when using `font-family:SomeFont;` In **HTML Styles**, it doesn't read my font and writes the text with the browser's default font!

And when reading that font, it gives these errors:

```
1- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sample.com/myfont.ttf. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

2- downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "SomeFont" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: https://sample.com/myfont.ttf
```

Image of error: [image: image-link]

#### What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: The solution is to host the fonts on the same domain (meaning no cross-origin) or asking/setting up the other server to provide the correct header to allow your site to use these files as if they are on the same domain (`Access-Allow-Origin: *`). There is no way around `CORS` otherwise, as it's meant to prevent you from just using another sites resources (and make them pay for it, which wouldn't be fair).

Comment: @somethinghere Thank you.
My control panel is CPanel. How can I accept permission the use of files only from other subdomains of my primary domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with the following solution:

Put these lines in the `.htaccess` file in the folder where the font file is. ( That is, create a `.htaccess` file in `https://sample.com/` )

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
</IfModule>
```

The above line allows your file to be read from any sites.